# Conditional Expectation of a product and sum of three Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I have a problem and I have no idea how to tackle it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The problem is the following:

Assume I have three mutually independent random variables $a$, $b$, and $c$, with:
$$ a\sim N(\mu_{a},\sigma_{a}^{2})$$
$$ b\sim N(\mu_{b},\sigma_{b}^{2})$$
$$ c\sim N(\mu_{c},\sigma_{c}^{2})$$

Also, assume:
$$y=ab+c$$

I'm interested in having an explicit formula for $E(a|y)$ in terms of $\mu_{i}$ and $\sigma_{i}^{2}$, for $i\in\{a,b,c\}$. How could I start to calculate such thing, if at all possible? If it makes calculations easier, we could further assume $\mu_{b}=0$ and $\sigma_{b}=1$.

Comment: This smells like homework. If it isn't, mark with the self-study tag and look up sum and product of independent random variables.

Answer (score 2):

Very good hint (but I won't solve your homework problem for you).

Let A and B be random variables.
Then E(A) = E(E(A|B)).  Choose A and B judiciously, and solving this problem is a snap.